# Pandas loc not working with pivot table, extra row in header

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am constantly running into this problem I am not sure if it is a pivot table or not but sometimes the dataframe header seems to have an extra row and then the loc command does not work.  How do I remove the white space between the column headers and the first row of data? Thanks

```
        ticker  open    high    low close   volume
date                        
2020-03-02  INO 4.40    4.500   3.83    4.390   15802231.0
2020-02-28  INO 4.79    4.890   3.93    4.280   25742363.0
2020-02-27  INO 4.44    5.000   4.10    4.360   34545815.0
2020-02-26  INO 3.80    4.040   3.73    3.990   13987098.0
2020-02-25  INO 4.02    4.068   3.60    3.735   9548068.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the name of your `index` , you can do `rename_axis`

```
df=df.rename_axis(None)
df
           ticker  open   high   low  close      volume
2020-03-02    INO  4.40  4.500  3.83  4.390  15802231.0
2020-02-28    INO  4.79  4.890  3.93  4.280  25742363.0
2020-02-27    INO  4.44  5.000  4.10  4.360  34545815.0
2020-02-26    INO  3.80  4.040  3.73  3.990  13987098.0
2020-02-25    INO  4.02  4.068  3.60  3.735   9548068.0
```